# Select all class inside a class but not a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to use a specific font for all elements but one class inside the most outer parent. Currently my code looks like this:

```css
.foo *:not(.bar) {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="foo">
  <a href="https://example.com"><span class="bar">Lorem</span></a>
  <a href="https://example.org"><span class="baz">ipsum</span></a>
  <span class="baz"> dolor</span>
  <span class="boo"> sit amet.</span>
</span>
```

Now, I want `Lorem` to stay as is, while applying the font to everything else. How can I do that?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. You can set one font-family for all `.foo *` and then override for the Lorem. Currently, your code will select only the direct child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the *[general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)* `~` does the trick.

```css
.foo :not(.bar) ~ * {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="foo">
  <a href="https://example.com"><span class="bar">Lorem</span></a>
  <a href="https://example.org"><span class="baz">ipsum</span></a>
  <span class="baz"> dolor</span>
  <span class="boo"> sit amet.</span>
</span>
```

But because `:not` is not supported in older browsers, i would recommend the following method (as mentioned by @m4n0), unless you don't need to support those.

```css
.foo * {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.foo .bar {
  font-family: initial;
}
```

```html
<span class="foo">
  <a href="https://example.com"><span class="bar">Lorem</span></a>
  <a href="https://example.org"><span class="baz">ipsum</span></a>
  <span class="baz"> dolor</span>
  <span class="boo"> sit amet.</span>
</span>
```